# return all items of an instance with hibernate primefaces

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I really have a problem that makes me crazy;
I want to search an instance in my database and return all the items of this instance in a JSF form in a `p:inputText`.

This is what I've done:

**This is the search method:**

```
public List findByCriteria(Class clazz, Criterion critere) { 

    List objects = null; 
    try { `openCurrentSessionwithTransaction(); `
        Criteria crit = currentSession.createCriteria(clazz).add(critere); 

        objects = crit.list(); 

    } catch (Exception e) { 

        e.printStackTrace(); 

    } finally { 
        currentSession.close(); 
    } 
    return objects;
}
```

**This is my method in the ClientCtr controller class :**

```
public void ChercherContact() { 
    try { 
        Client clt = new Client(); 
        System.out.println("id " + idSociete); 
        Criterion critere = Restrictions.eq("idSociete", 
        client.getIdSociete()); 
        List<Client> l = ClientDao.findByCriteria(Client.class, critere); 
        clt = l.get(0); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

**And this is my form :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 


<h:form id="f"> 
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin: 0 auto"> 
<p:graphicImage value="ooredoo.jpg" 
style="height : 204px; width : 590px; margin: 0 auto " /> 

</h:panelGrid> 
<h:panelGrid columns="4" style="margin: 0 auto"> 
<h:outputText value="ID CLIENT:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 

<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.idSociete}" id="id_societe" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight:bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"> 
</p:inputText> 
<p:commandButton action="#{clientCtr.ChercherContact}" 
update="f" value="CHERCHER" 
style="background-color:Red;color:White;font-weight: bold;font-size: large;border-color:Black;float:center;border-style:outset; width : 176px;"> 
</p:commandButton> 
<p:commandButton id="quitter" value="QUITTER" action="e" 
onclick="window.close()" 
style="background-color:Red;color:White;font-weight: bold;font-size: large;border-color:Black;float:center;border-style:outset; width : 176px;"> 
</p:commandButton> 
</h:panelGrid> 
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto" id="grid"> 
<h:outputText value="Nom De La Société:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.nomSociete}" id="nom_societe" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 

<h:outputText value="ID De La Société:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.idSociete}" id="id_societes" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="Route:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.route}" id="route" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="NCGR:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.ncgr}" id="ncgr" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="FQDN:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.fqdn}" id="fqdn" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="RTGRP:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.rtgrp}" id="rtgrp" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="OUTBPROXY:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.outbproxy}" id="outbproxy" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="Directory Number:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.directoryNumber}" 
id="directory_number" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="NDEST:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.ndest}" id="ndest" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="Operator Number:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.operatorNumber}" 
id="operateur_number" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
<h:outputText value="Additional DN :" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<h:selectOneListbox value="additional_dn" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight:bold;border-color:Red;border-border-style:solid; width : 169px; " /> 

<h:outputText value="SCRI:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.scri}" id="scri" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 

<h:outputText value="UPDI:" 
style="FONT-SIZE: large; COLOR: #ff0000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{clientCtr.client.upd}" id="updi" 
style="background-color:White;font-weight: bold;border-width:medium;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;"></p:inputText> 
</h:panelGrid> 
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto"> 


<p:commandButton id="quittere" value="QUITTER" action="e" 
onclick="window.close()" 
style="background-color:Red;color:White;font-weight: bold;font-size: large;border-color:Black;float:center;border-style:outset; width : 176px;" /> 

</h:panelGrid> 
</h:form> 
</html>
```

if I run the form,when I click the search button, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at tn.ooredoo.kpi.controller.ClientCtr.ChercherContact(ClientCtr.java:210)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I test something else, when I remove all the `inputtext` and I leave just one `inputtext`, it works good and it get the right item of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ClientDao.findByCriteria(Client.class, critere)` is returning an empty list, from wich you are trying to get an element: `clt = l.get(0)` and as a result you get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: i think no because if i test it in a console, when i do l.size() it returns me 1, that means that there is Client in the list

Comment: Replace 'clt = l.get(0);' with 'clt = !l.isEmpty() ? l.get(0) : null;' and check if you are still getiing this exception.

Comment: Szarpul: when i replace by what you tell me, it removes the exception but it does not appear the information of the client in the form

Comment: Now you probably get NullPointerException somewhere in the JSF rendering phase. Instead of null you can return new instance: new Client(). However, the point was to show you that your method did return empty list. How you want to handle it, it's up to you.

Comment: no no there is no NullPointerException and my methode return a list with one client i tested it and i confirm that,

Comment: I told you, for me its empty list. Your function may work correctly, but are you sure that during tests you pass same arguments to the function?